# java image not moving

Tags: java, image, animation

Hi guys im working on a game. But for some reason the Image won't appear nor move.

Here is some Code.

TheScreen.java

```
package TheCarePackage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TheScreen extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

short FWIDTH = 500;
short FHEIGHT = 500;

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbGraphics;

private Image Bg;

static Player_1 P1 = new Player_1(250,450);
static AlienSpawner AS = new AlienSpawner();

public TheScreen(){

    addKeyListener(this);
    setTitle("1st Game");
    setSize(FWIDTH,FHEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    ImageIcon back = new      ImageIcon("C:/Users/yellowsoldier25/Desktop/Games/PlanB_1stGame/src/TheCarePackage/Images/Background.png");
    Bg = back.getImage();

}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
    dbGraphics = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbGraphics);
    g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(Bg,0,0,this);
    P1.draw(g);
    AS.paint(g);

    repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new TheScreen();

    Thread As = new Thread(AS);
    Thread Player1 = new Thread(P1);
    As.start();
    Player1.start();

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    P1.keyPressed(e);

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}



}
```

ThePlayer.java

```
package TheCarePackage;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Player_1 implements Runnable{

public int a = 8;

int x,y;
Image Player_1;

private Shot[] shots;
static AlienSpawner AS = new AlienSpawner();

public Player_1(int x, int y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/yellowsoldier25/Desktop/Games/PlanB_1stGame/src/TheCarePackage/Images/Player_1.png");
    Player_1 = i.getImage();

    shots = new Shot[8];

}

public void draw(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(Player_1,x,y,50,50,null);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Ammo : " + a,10,40);

    for(int i = 0; i < shots.length; i++){

        if(shots[i] != null){

            shots[i].drawShot(g);

        }

    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT){

        x += -8;

    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT){

        x += 8;

    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_SPACE){

    for(int i = 0; i < shots.length; i++){

        if(shots[i] == null){

            a--;
            shots[i] = generateShot();
            break;

        }

    }

    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public Shot generateShot(){

    Shot shot = new Shot(x+23,y-7);

    return shot;

}

@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        while(true){

            Thread.sleep(5);

            for(int i = 0; i < shots.length; i++){

                if(shots[i] != null){

                    shots[i].moveShot(-1);

                    if(shots[i].getY() < 0){

                        shots[i] = null;
                        a++;

                    }


                }

            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
}

}
```

theProblem...

TheAlienSpawner.java

```
package TheCarePackage;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AlienSpawner implements Runnable{

private int Health = 3;

private Shot s;

private boolean Spawn = true;

public AlienSpawner(){}

Alien1stVariant A1 = new Alien1stVariant(250,0);

public void paint(Graphics g){

    A1.drawAlien(g);

}

public void run() {

    try{

        Thread.sleep(20);

    while(true){

    A1.movement(1);

    }

    }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
}

}
```

The Alien Class The other problem...

```
package TheCarePackage;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Alien1stVariant {

private int x;
private int y;

private Image Alien;

public Alien1stVariant(int x, int y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    ImageIcon AlienIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/yellowsoldier25/Desktop/Games/PlanB_1stGame/src/TheCarePackage/Images/Alien.png");
    Alien = AlienIcon.getImage();

}

public int getX(){

    return x;

}

public int getY(){

    return y;

}

public void movement(int speed){

    y += speed;

}

public void drawAlien(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(Alien,x,y,40,40,null);

}

}
```

Please help as soon as possible please.

Problem: Alien Image won't move and appear.

Comment: What have you learned when debugging this?

Comment: That the image will not move, it won't shot but if i remove the run methods then it will show, but still wont move.

Comment: This is a question about diaplaying and animating an image. How is that a "local question"? Many people have these problems. Get over yourself guys and try to make a postive contribution to the forum instead of attacking a person making there first posting on the site.

Answer (score 1):

JFrame doesn't have a paintComponent() method so don't try to override it.

You should rarely override the paint() method either. Instead custom painting is done by extending JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the content pane of the frame.

If you want to do animation the use a Swing Timer now a while loop with a sleep().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an infinite cycle in your TheAlienSpawner.java file inside the run method:

```
public void run() {
    try{
        Thread.sleep(20);
    while(true){ //This will never end
    A1.movement(1);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```

You just sleep the tread once for 20 ms before the While(true) that causes an infinite loop , what you're looking for is something similar to this:

```
public void run() {
   try{
       while(true){
           Thread.sleep(20);
           A1.movement(1);
       }
    }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```